# Store Git Log in some variable in YAML pipeline - Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, yaml, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

```
name: "Sample"

trigger:
- main


pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables: 
- template: Pipeline/vars/global-pipeline.vars.yaml
- name: gitLog
  value: ''

steps:

- script: |
    $gitLog = git log
    echo $gitLog
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
  displayName: 'Fetch Git Log and Store in a variable'
```

Above is my sample Azure DevOps Yaml pipeline and My goal is here to get "Git Log", store in some variable and pass it for some other operation in this pipeline. I have declared a variable *gitLog* and I want to fetch value of git command  *git log* and store in git log using below task but I am getting error -

> '$gitLog' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Ubuntu VM**

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables: 
- name: gitLog
  value: ''

steps:
- script: |
    gitLog=$(git log)
    echo $gitLog
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=gitLog]$(echo $gitLog)"
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
  displayName: 'Fetch Git Log and Store in a variable'
- script: |
    echo "As pipeline variable gitLog: $(gitLog)"
    echo "As environment variable GITLOG: $GITLOG"
```

**Using Windows VM**

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables: 
- name: gitLog
  value: ''

steps:
- powershell: |
    $gitLog=git log
    echo $gitLog
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=gitLog]$(echo $gitLog)"
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
  displayName: 'Fetch Git Log and Store in a variable'
- script: |
    echo "Pipeline variables gitLog: $(gitLog)"
```

**Note:** You need to use `task.setvariable` to set your pipeline variable `gitLog`, it is NOT the same as the bash variable `$gitLog`

**Demo Run**

[image]

Read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#about-tasksetvariable) for more details

Comment: why it does not work with 'windows-latest' ? Can I run it on windows VM?

Comment: Because Windows.... The [CmdLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/cmd-line-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task uses cmd.exe on Windows VM and that wouldn't be the same as bash, although it would be much easier to use PowerShell with Windows VM, do you have hard requirement to use Windows VM?

Comment: Updated for Windows VM as well. @F11

Comment: error in Windows VM - "workingDirectory: : The term 'workingDirectory:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
"

Comment: Make sure to get the indentation correct. Otherwise use the [full form of the PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines#syntax)

Comment: For the Ubuntu VM example, it should be `bash` instead of `script`.